Facing the Anchor-Rustc Version Mismatch Problem
Since I started using anchor I have been facing this problem where whenever i use the anchor build command, then my IDE-terminal shows me this error:

error: package solana-program v1.18.20 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.20 --precise ver
where ver is the latest version of solana-program supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev

I used to delete my cargo.lock file and then wrote the command `cargo add solana-program@=1.17.0?
but this only fixes the problem temporarily, as soon as I add any new dependencies the version mismatch continues. Or even If I create a new anchor project this problem persists. What should I do?

solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.4 (src:356c6a38; feat:3352961542, client:SolanaLabs)
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.20 --precise 1.18.4

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
